# How to insert data into table taking table name value from form?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<? if($_POST['submit'])
{   $taskSelect =$_POST['taskOption'];

    $sql =array();
    foreach($_POST['task'] as $key => $value){
$sql[] =mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
    $ab ="INSERT INTO" .$taskSelect. "(u_id,task) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."','".implode(',', $sql)."')";
}
$asc =mysql_query($ab);
 ?>
```

HTML

Is it possible to do so , As i've tried this but no value is being inserted into table when I'm using table name taken from form?

```
<select name="taskOption">
 <option value="today">Today</option>
  <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
  <option value="month">Monthly</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Be sure to escape `$taskSelect` if not changing to prepared statements.

Comment: @Dan: better is to limit the possibilities in a `switch` statement. Prepared statements do not allow for table replacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss some spaces:

```
$ab ="INSERT INTO" .$taskSelect. "(u_id,task) VALUES ('".$...
```

should be

```
$ab ="INSERT INTO " .$taskSelect. " (u_id,task) VALUES ('".$...
```

That being said, do not use `mysql_*` anymore, read up on prepared statements and input validation. You are wide open to SQL injection right now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a space after INTO and before "

```
$ab ="INSERT INTO " .$taskSelect. "(u_id,task) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."','".implode(',', $sql)."')";
```